# Find the last two digits of $2019^{2018}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the last two digits of $2019^{2018}$.

Since $2019\equiv19\pmod{100}$, I can write:
$$19^{2018}\mod100$$

Now,
$$19^{2018}=19^{2000}\times19^{18}=(19^{40})^{50}\times19^{18}$$

Because $19^{40}\equiv1\pmod{100}$ (**Euler's theorem**), it becomes:
$$19^{18}\mod100$$
From here, I don't know what to do next to solve this, any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: This is an (abstract) dupe and will likely soon be closed as such (but I don't have time to search at the moment)

Answer (score 2):

$$19^{2018}=(20-1)^{2018}=100k-2018\times20+1=100k'+41$$
Therefore the last digit of $2019^{2018}$ is $41$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is 41. Because... (I'll start right there, where you stopped.)

> $$19^{18}=(19^2)^9=361^9\equiv61^9=(60+1)^9=100(\text{some terms})+\binom{9}{1}60^11^8+\binom{9}{0}60^01^9\\\equiv9\times60+1\equiv41\pmod{100}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use binomial theorem

$19^{18}=(20-1)^{18}=20^{18}-18\cdot 20^{17}+9\cdot17\cdot20^{16}-\dots+\binom{18}{16}\cdot 20^2-\binom{18}{17}\cdot 20+1$

$19^{18}\equiv\mod(100)=(100k-360+1)\equiv\mod(100)=(100k-359)\equiv \mod(100)=41\mod(100)$

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is to see if there are any (semi-)clever tricks that simplify the arithmetic. Here's one approach:

$$19^{18}\equiv(-81)^{18}=9^{36}=(1-10)^{36}\equiv1-360\equiv1-60=-59\equiv41\pmod{100}$$